# How to check factory bot creates unique models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Is there any way of doing the linting of factory bot (previously known as factory girl) to check that unique models are created (for example if more than one `Person` is created, and there's a validation that names must be unique, that factory bot generates person objects with unique names), other than doing something like

```
begin
  DatabaseCleaner.start
  FactoryGirl.lint
  # Run twice to ensure uniqueness isn't an issue
  FactoryGirl.lint
ensure
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

It works, but doesn't seem very graceful.

Background: I added a uniqueness validation to a model, but failed to modify the factories for the models, and it caused some tests to fail, because multiple records were made which violated the uniqueness validation. However, the linting didn't detect this problem, because it only attempted to create one of each model, and it was able to do that fine. I want to change the linting so it would detect such a problem.

Comment: Are you asking about how to test uniqueness validations, or how to achieve creating unique objects with FactoryBot (or something else)? What is your intention with using FactoryBot.lint in your test configuration?

Comment: `name { Faker::Name.unique.name }` does it help?

Comment: @inveterateliterate just checking - are you familiar with the purpose of FactoryGirl.lint ?

Comment: From my understanding of the docs, it’s to make sure factories are properly defined (they use the word valid) before running tests: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md. That to me isn’t the same thing as testing validations you’ve set on your models.

Comment: @inveterateliterate I've updated the question.

Comment: Thanks, I did misunderstand the use of lint. From further research the recommendations I have come across include passing a block with random (Faker) data or using sequence: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/623, https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/674